# Characterization of the epigraph of a lower semi continuous fuction

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

The goal is to prove that if epigraph of a function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is closed then it is lower semicontinuous. The epigraph of $f$, $\operatorname{epi} f$ is given as
$$
\operatorname{epi} f = \{ (x, r): f(x) \leq r \}
$$

while a lower semicontinuous function is defined as a function for which:
$$
f(\bar{x}) \leq \liminf_{u \rightarrow \bar{x}} f(u)
$$
for all $\bar{x} \in X$, where $X$ is a normed space. I have been able to prove the converse but need some pointers on how to proceed in this direction.

Comment: Hint 1: Try to express the lower semi-continuity of $f$ in terms of neighbourhoods of $\bar{x}$. 
Hint 2: The epigraph is closed iff its complement is open.

Comment: I changed \text{epi } (with a blank space after the "i") to \operatorname{epi} (with no such space). The latter adds space or not depending on the context, and is standard. I also changed \underset{...} \text{lim inf } to \liminf_{...}, and you see the result. That is also standard usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}$ such that  $x_{n }\to x_0\in X$ and suppose $\liminf f(x_n)<f(x_0).$ Then, there is a $\gamma$ and a subsequence $\left \{ x_{n_k} \right \}$ such that $f(x_{n_k})\le \gamma<f(x_0).$ Therefore, $(x_{n_k},\gamma )\in \text{epi} f.$ But now we have a contradiction, because since $x_{n_k}\to x_0$ and the epigraph is closed, we should have $f(x_0)\le \gamma.$

Comment: I have one question though. You say $x_{n_k} \rightarrow x_0$ and then imply that $f(x_{n_k}) \rightarrow f(x_0)$, but we do not have any continuity assumptions on $f$.

Comment: No, I don't  think so. Here's the argument: The set $\left \{ (x_{n_k},\gamma ) \right \}_k$ is contained in epi$f$ and has limit point $(x_0,\gamma)$ and as epi$f$ is closed by assumption, this point must be in epi$f$ and that is how we conclude that $f(x_0)\le \gamma.$ Never said anything about whether or not $f$ is continuous, I suppose you do need to show that the sequence $(x_n)$ with the stated property exists, but that is an easy consequence of the definition of $\liminf.$